# using array_search or loop in PHP to find the position of a key

Tags: php

I wrote this code to find domain names in an array in PHP. My question is how to find the position of the key without using a loop.

I wrote both forms to show my meaning.

```
    <?php
    $unique_domains = array( "www.crownworldwide.com","www.acquisition.gov", "www.hemisphere-freight.com",
"www.businessinsider.com","www.oceansidelogistics.com","mixjet.aero","www.airindiaexpress.in", "rlglobal.com",
"www.metroshipping.co.uk","www.flexport.com"
);

$position = array_search("flexport.com",$unique_domains);

echo "position is ". $position . "<br>";

<----------------------------------------->
    $position2 = 0 ;
    foreach ($unique_domains as $key ) {
    $position2++;
    if(preg_match('/'.preg_quote("flexport.com").'\b/',$key)){
    echo "position is ".$position2 ;
    }


    }
    
    ?>
```

On the first method I was not able to find the position as it has www. at the beginning. On the second method I can find the position but I do not want to use a loop in my live platform. What are the alternative to find the domain names inside an array?

**Update:**
Also the result must be domain specific and all subdomains must be accepted.

For example:
**flexport.com :**

flexport.co - is wrong

app.flexport.co is correct

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop on your live platform?

Comment: How many times per script execution this search has to be performed?

Comment: can different subdomains of the same domain occur? if so, which position must be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [`preg_match()`](https://php.net/preg_match) and a simple `foreach`. This method avoid the iteration of all items of the array and stops when a match is found.

```php
/**
 * Returns the index of the first match or false if not found.
 */
function arraySearch(array $array, string $search): int|false
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match('~' . $search . '$~',$value)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$unique_domains = [
    'www.crownworldwide.com',
    'www.acquisition.gov',
    'www.hemisphere-freight.com',
    'www.businessinsider.com',
    'www.oceansidelogistics.com',
    'mixjet.aero',
    'www.airindiaexpress.in',
    'rlglobal.com',
    'www.metroshipping.co.uk',
    'www.flexport.com'
];

var_dump(arraySearch($unique_domains, 'flexport.co')); // bool(false)
var_dump(arraySearch($unique_domains, 'flexport.com')); // int(9)
```

- [live demo](https://3v4l.org/AWFWC) PHP 8.0
- [live demo](https://3v4l.org/KeuZk) PHP 7.4

Comment: Same problem. Check with flexport.co please. You will see the position for that wrong domain.

Comment: this one is closest, you only need to change strpos to substr or preg_match

Comment: Technically, -1 is a legit key, so I'd rather make this function return `int|false` making its behavior closer to the bulitin function.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tend to agree with this idea. The use of the "int" type was interesting for the "unique" type, before PHP 8.0 (or nullable, but not necessarily more interesting). I have modified the answer accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$unique_domains = [
    'www.crownworldwide.com',
    'www.acquisition.gov',
    'www.hemisphere-freight.com',
    'www.businessinsider.com',
    'www.oceansidelogistics.com',
    'mixjet.aero',
    'www.airindiaexpress.in',
    'rlglobal.com',
    'www.metroshipping.co.uk',
    'www.flexport.com'
];

$position = array_key_first(array_filter($unique_domains, fn($val) => str_contains($val, 'flexport.com')));

echo 'position is ' . $position;
```

Comment: Nice approach but it shows the position 9 instead of 10. But thats okay

Comment: There is another problem here. If I look for flexport.co it shows the position while there is no such a domain in the array. it is .com.

Comment: that's too much loops here

Comment: @Farshad: position 9 is correct (arrays in PHP are zero-based). And your second comment about 'flexport.co' does not make sense – maybe you haven't scrolled to the right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = preg_quote('flexport.com', '~'); // don't forget to quote input string!
$data = array("www.crownworldwide.com","www.acquisition.gov", "www.hemisphere-freight.com",
"www.businessinsider.com","www.oceansidelogistics.com","mixjet.aero","www.airindiaexpress.in", "rlglobal.com",
"www.metroshipping.co.uk","www.flexport.com");

$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $data);
var_dump($result); // array(1) { [9]=> string(16) "www.flexport.com" }
array_keys($result); // [9]
```

Comment: The code has the same mistake, if I look for flexport.co it is still showing the position for .com . So the answer is not correct.

Comment: I changed the code to this and it seems to fix the problem : $result = preg_grep('/' . $input . '\b/', $data);

Comment: You asked for not using the loop, but to be specific for the same domain name as you want you can write  `$result = preg_grep('/' . $input . '$/i', $data);` and it will work @Farshad

Comment: Thanks but still app.domain.com as a subdomain must be accepted but not with that code.

Comment: the loop is inefficient

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2.0

I think we should take a simple and pragmatic approach here. The goal is to only get the index of an array if the search domain matches. Regardless of whether with www. or without.

A function that accepts a search string. Remove the www. in the search string as well as the values of the array. This way you compare domain with domain. and you only get unique results. Then return the key. that's it!

```php
<?php

function position($search) {  
  $unique_domains = [
    'www.crownworldwide.com',
    'www.acquisition.gov',
    'www.hemisphere-freight.com',
    'www.businessinsider.com',
    'www.oceansidelogistics.com',
    'mixjet.aero',
    'www.airindiaexpress.in',
    'rlglobal.com',
    'www.metroshipping.co.uk',
    'www.flexport.com'
];
  
    foreach($unique_domains as $k => $v)
    {
       $plain_1 = str_replace("www.","",$v);    
       $plain_2 = str_replace("www.","",$search);    
       if($plain_1 == $plain_2) {
         return $k;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

print_r('flexport.com => ' .position('flexport.com')); // 9
echo '<br/>';
print_r('www.flexport.com => ' . position('www.flexport.com')); // 9
echo '<br/>';
print_r('om' . position('om')); // 0
```

**working example (updated 2.0) **
https://3v4l.org/B4TAu#v8.1.2

Comment: Same mistake. Wrong answer for flexport.co . It should show 0 position for not the exact domain suffixes like .co

Comment: @Farshad Yes you are right becuase multiple matches. i fixed. thanks for hint

Comment: inside the demo : It returns 1 instead of 9

Comment: too much loops.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Of course. I updateded my answer again. last time ;-)

Comment: @Farshad I  updtaed again and last time :-)

Comment: what would happen to audi-www.com domain?

Comment: there must be no str_replace in this code